# How to move drupal site from remote server to localhost?

Tags: migrations

I have a drupal site running currently on bluehost.
The site is big and I want to test every thing I change on local host before doing it on production site.

Unfortunately, I can not move it to from the remote server to local host.

Can someone give me the basic steps needed to move site from remote server to my local host (aquia dev desktop)?

Comment: it your host support ssh?

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: do you access cpanel?

Comment: what is your OS , windows or Mac on linux?

Comment: I have access to cpanel. My OS on my desktop computer is windows.

Comment: good , if you has access to cpanel you can zip drupal directory and download it easier ,

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure your site has SSH access and you can access it, but certainly you have FTP access to your site.
Suppose your drupal directory is /public_html/mydrupalsite/; with FTP managers like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [CuteFtp](http://www.cuteftp.com/) access your site. Download all the files that are in the mydrupalsite directory, then  go to phpmyadmin on your site, and select your database; open the export tab, and export your database without changing any setting.
Install PHP, Apache, and MySQL server on your computer, copy the files to the directory that can run in your local host, create a new database, import the  database, and change the parameters in the settings.php file.